# How to get the undo / swap controls in Visual Studio 2022 diff window?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2022 (17.8.6): when I comparing git version of a code file (or compare the current file to the last version) there was an option to swap sections from left to right. I believe these appeared when mouse-hovering over the section. But now, no matter where I click or hover, I cannot get this option anymore.